# async function on route.js file | nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have an application that it has nodejs as backend and some scripts in Python

The problem is to make the 'PythonShell' (function to access the scripts) as a async function. I do not know why but it is not working.

I'll put the code from my router.js file and inside of it I put three 'console.log('steps')' to check the sequences.

It should be Step01 > Step02 > Step03, but as it is not working, It always prints Step01 > Step03 > Step02

Everything is working fine, except for this async problem! For me it should work as it is.

How can I edit my functions to execute first the 'goToscript/PythonShell' and then execute 'res.json(responseScript)'?

Thanks

```
   router.put("/uploads/script-03", async (req, res) => {

    let options = {
        scriptPath: "scripts",
        args: JSON.stringify(req.body)
    };

    const goToScript = async () => {
        
        await PythonShell.run("script-01.py", options, (err, res) => {
            if (err) {
            }
            if (res) {
                responseScript = JSON.parse(res)
                console.log('Step 02')
            }
        });
    }

    console.log('Step 01')

    goToScript()
    
    console.log('Step 03')
    
    res.json(responseScript)
});

module.exports = router
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple things:

**1. Your `goToScript` is not actually async/returning a Promise**

From what I can tell, `PythonShell` doesn't support async, only callbacks, so you can rewrite your `gotToScript` like so:

```js
const goToScript = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    PythonShell.run("script-01.py", options, (err, res) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err)
      }

      if (res) {
        responseScript = JSON.parse(res)
        console.log('Step 02')

        resolve(responseScript)
      }
    })
  })
}

const scriptResult = await goToScript()
```

This code will work like a regular `async` function, where the promise will resolve to the parsed JSON, and reject with the error if it meets one.

**2. You are not `await`ing your call to `goToScript`**

When you want to make an async call that finishes in sequence with everything else, you need to `await` it. Take these two examples:

In this first chunk of code, `waitFn` waits before 100ms before logging "Step 2!":

```js
const waitFn = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('Step 2!')
      resolve()
    }, 100)
  })
}

console.log('Step 1!')
waitFn()
console.log('Step 3!')
```

Because you do not `await` the result of the `Promise`, your code doesn't care that is has not finished, and will print:

```
Step 1!
Step 3!
Step 2!
```

Instead, however, if you `await` the result of the `Promise` returned in `waitFn`, it will execute in order:

```js
const waitFn = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('Step 2!')
      resolve()
    }, 100)
  })
}

console.log('Step 1!')
await waitFn() // Finishes before moving on
console.log('Step 3!')
```

You can read a bunch more about Promises and async/await [here](https://javascript.info/promise-basics) :)

Comment: Everything is working fine! Thanks

Also, very interesting the link about Promises and Async/Await! I gonna read it to solve my problem with Promises

I was using it before but always with some issues! Lets fix it. Thanks a lot ;)

Answer (score 0):

To be able to `await` function - this function needs to return a `promise`. In the [npm page of your lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-shell) there is a description, about what `PythonShell.run` returns. It does not return a promise. So it is asynchronous, but not awaitable, it is `callback` based.

All you need to do - to `promisify` this function. Additionaly - you need to `await` the call to `goToScript();`.

```
router.put("/uploads/script-03", async (req, res) => {
  let options = {
    scriptPath: "scripts",
    args: JSON.stringify(req.body)
  };

  const goToScript = async () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      PythonShell.run("script-01.py", options, (err, res) => {
        console.log("Step 02");
        if (err) return reject(err);
        return resolve(JSON.parse(res));
      });
    });
  };

  console.log("Step 01");
  const responseScript = await goToScript();
  
  console.log("Step 03");
  res.json(responseScript);
});

module.exports = router;
```